# error: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_X8A5XK//dev: No such file or directory

Tags: mount, snap

There is a problem with the snaps that I install; they won't launch and return with this error:

`mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_X8A5XK//dev: No such file or directory`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because snap is not in the $PATH

I had this issue aswell. Restarted the computer solved the issue.

See if that helps

Comment: Tnx for your help. But unfortunately i don't have that os anymore so no problem!

Comment: @mmafsahri Yes I see. I just stumbled upon this error myself, and found the solution. Just felt like posting this because nobody had answered